# Whether the Sync button mix together the pull and push functions in github-desktop?

Tags: git, github-desktop

In git terminal, we know we should

```
git pull origin 
git push origin
```

to let the origin repo to pull to our local repo, and push our merged master to origin repo.

and in github desktop, I did not see pull and push button, only see the Sync button:

[image]

Whether the Sync button mix together the pull and push function in there?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct; it does mix those commands together. The `Sync` button can perform a `Fetch origin`, `Pull origin`, or `Push origin` depending on the context.

In newer versions of GitHub Desktop, it will actually display which action will happen if the button were to be pressed. The `Sync` button might look like this if a fetch is the relevant action:

[image: GitHub Desktop Fetch Button]

like this if a pull is:

[image: GitHub Desktop Pull Button]

or like this if a push is:

[image: GitHub Desktop Push Button]

In the version you're using, the `Sync` button won't necessarily tell you what it will do until after you press it. But you can assume it will pull if it detected changes, fetch if it does not, and push if you have local changes. It may even do a combination of pull and push if there are no merge conflicts.